# Move/Rename a file using FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to moving a file from one folder to another using FtpWebRequest but i keep getting error 550. This is my code;

```
var requestMove = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Helper.PathFtp + Helper.NewFolder + file);
requestMove.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
requestMove.Credentials = networkCredential;
requestMove.RenameTo = "../" + Helper.OldFolder + file;
requestMove.GetResponse();
```

I can list, upload, download and delete files but moving/renaming is hopeless. I have read several posts both on stackoverflow and other sites and have tried things like setting Proxy to null and adding special characters to paths but I cant find a solution that works.

The path I use in WebRequest.Create is correct as I can delete it so it must be the RenameTo I got an issue with. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 550 means access denied. If the ftp user has sufficient rights, a program (e.g. antivirus, windows thumbnail generator etc) could have the file opened and deny your move request.

You need to contact the server administrator to get around the problem.

Comment: I have access to delete and create files - moving files should then also be possible. Using a FTP-program with same credentials also lets me move files so in this case I dont think that it is an issue with the rights. When looking closer to the exception it is saying that the file or folder is not found but it does exist (tested with the download and delete option) so it must be RenameTo that is somehow wrong even if i just set it to '"RENAMED" + file' which should just rename the file and not move it.

Comment: Then check what commands are sent from the FTP software and replay the commands in your code.

Comment: When the FTP software renames it uses a long path (/folder1/folder2/folder3/userfolder/test) and using this in my code actually works. The only problem is that this path is only known for me in this test-scenarie and even if I knew it it could easely change. The user has only access to "userfolder" and up.